# Finding the length of a train confusion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

Erica noted that a train to Muizenberg took $8$ minutes to pass her. A train in
the opposite direction to Cape Town took $12$ minutes to pass her. The trains
took $9 $ minutes to pass each other. Assuming each train maintained a constant
speed, and given that the train to Cape Town was $ 150$m long, what was the
length of the train to Muizenberg?

My attempt:

let $x$ be the length of the train to Muizenberg.

let $s_1$ be the speed of the train to Muizenberg.

let $s_2$ be the speed of the train to Cape Town.

let $t_1 =$ the time it takes the train to Muizenberg to pass the train to Cape Town

let $t_2 =$ the time it takes the train to Cape Town to pass the train to Muizenberg

We have $x = 8 \times s_1$

$$s_2 = \frac{150}{12} = 12.5$$

Now by the third statement, if it takes $9$ minutes for the two trains to pass each other then $$t_1 = t_2$$
$$ \frac{150}{12.5} = \frac{x}{s_1} = 9$$ (Since $Time = \frac{distance}{Speed}$.)

But clearly there is something wrong in my solution. Where did I go wrong? Can someone explain to me what is my **mistake**? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You mistake is in the fact that when the two trains pass each other, the relative speed is the *sum* of their speed, and the length is the sum of their lengths. Letting $s_1$ (resp. $s_2$) be the speed of the first train (resp the second) relative to Erica, you get 
$$
9\cdot 60 = \frac{x+150}{s_1+s_2}
$$
(the multiplication by 60 being to express the speeds in $m.s^{-1}$).